# Python Trouble Importing Local Package Inside Local Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

this is my first post on here and I'm also fairly new to python, for the past two days I've been struggling with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import PyScrape
File "/Users/arya/Desktop/Coding/Python/x/x/PyScrape/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import ProxyScraper
File "/Users/arya/Desktop/Coding/Python/x/x/PyScrape/ProxyScraper/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import FreeProxyList
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProxyScraper'
```

when trying to import the "ProxyScraper" directory in the `__init__.py` file within the "PyScrape" directory, my file structure is below, let me know if I need to disclose more information.

```
PyScrape/
    __init__.py
    ProxyChecker.py
    ProxyScraper/
        __init__.py
        CheckerProxy.py
        FreeProxyList.py
        Hidester.py
        HttpTunnel.py
        PremProxy.py
        SpysMe.py
        Utility.py
```

The contents of the `__init__.py` within the "PyScrape" directory is the following:

```
from . import ProxyScraper
from . import ProxyChecker

def Scrape():
     return ProxyChecker.CheckProxyList(ProxyScraper.Scrape())
```

The contents of the `__init__.py` within the "ProxyScraper" directory is as follows:
    from threading import Thread
    from queue import Queue

```
from . import FreeProxyList
from . import Hidester
from . import CheckerProxy
from . import SpysMe
from . import HttpTunnel

SourceArray = ["FreeProxyList", "Hidester", "CheckerProxy", "SpysMe", "HttpTunnel"]

def Scrape():
    WorkerList = []
    ProxyQueue = Queue()

    for Source in SourceArray:
        Worker = Thread(name=Source, target=eval(Source + ".Scrape"), args=(ProxyQueue,))
        WorkerList.append(Worker)
        Worker.start()

    for Worker in WorkerList:
        Worker.join()

    return ProxyQueue
```

Comment: Is ProxyScrapper.py the name of the directory?

Comment: @yorodm It's not, that was a typo, I should've read my post over before posting 

Comment: Which `__init__.py` are you trying to import your package in? Also could you show us the contents of said `__init__.py`?

Comment: Could you please post the import statement you are using along with the complete error message?

Comment: @raratiru
`from . import ProxyScraper`

Comment: @Hevlastka Added to the question, sorry for not including that originally

Comment: OK, how are you running your program and which is the full error message? Can you show the exact steps to follow so I can reproduce the same error in another box?

Comment: Nice one thanks @Arya! Like raratru mentioned could you give us a full error message you're getting (including the stacktrace). Also could you tell us is there anything in the other `__init__,py` file or is it empty?

Comment: @raratiru Added full error, once again sorry I totally missed the part where you asked for the full error

Comment: @Hevlastka Added both the stack trace and the contents of the `__init__.py` file within the ProxyScraper directory

Comment: OK, we are getting closer! I have created a structure like you describe, I have added all the imports in the relevant files, which command do you type and where? How can I receive that error?

Comment: @raratiru I essentially import the PyScrape packages into one of my projects and call the Scrape function that was declared in the `__init__.py` file of that directory and when I go to run that file using the usual `python3.7 Main.py` that error gets thrown

Comment: Instead of `from .` have you tried to define the parent module? For example: `from PyScrape import ProxyChecker`

Comment: @raratiru Just tried to import it that way and was met with the same error, I'm really confused and have no idea why I can't import a local directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a python module to be imported, its containing directory must be set either in a [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) variable in `$HOME/.bashrc` file for example, or explicitly inserted in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.path) during runtime.

One solution would be:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/PyScrape')
```

Another would be:

```
$ echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/PyScrape' >> $HOME/.bashrc
$ source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Bear in mind that instead of `.bashrc` the relevant file could be `.profile`.

When you set `PYTHONPATH` then the result of the command:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

will contain the path you set in `$PYTHONPATH` because:

> `sys.path` is a list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

Comment: how am I able to import the PyScrape directory without adding it to sys.path then, or does this only apply to when importing a package from a subfolder inside a folder being imported?

Comment: I did mark your answer as the correct one as it did fix the situation, but there must surely be a cleaner way of doing this

Comment: @Arya By adding the directory to the enviroment variable `PYTHONPATH`, it is actually added to `sys.path`. As the linked documentation of `sys.path` mentions: "A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default."